# Can being fastidious and delicate (איסטניס) get lenience in cleaning for Pesach?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, food, passover, chametz-leaven

The agricultural and technological revolutions changed a lot in our perception of food and we all became more fastidious and delicate (is it good for איסטניס?) - we even have expiration dates on everything edible.

As such, we are not suspected to eat anything off floor or whatever can be found under the mattress or in the diapers drawer or a spoiled sandwich in my son's bag.

Do those trends lead to changes in the Halacha regarding cleaning for Pesach, because most of it is based on that very fear that a person would consume it?

<sub>Please feel free to edit my English</sub>.

Comment: The opposite is true: nowadays bread you find a few day later is significantly more edible than in yesteryear.

Comment: The point of looking for crumbs was never that you may claim them, the gemorrah specifically mentions that.

For larger objects, I think it's reasonable that some, especially younger children, will eat a pretzel if you find it under a mattress

Comment: The lower threshold is that even a *dog* would eat it, not that even a *human* would eat it. Dogs eat food off the floor all the time.

Comment: @Doniel that's the threshold for a prohibition if you'd eat, not the threshold for when we fear you might eat it.

Comment: @DoubleAA Isn’t it the threshold for בל יראה בל ימצא as well? Pesachim 2:3 specifically discusses a case of if something collapsed on the chametz is it considered as having been destroyed - that’s a בל יראה issue, not an אכילת חמץ issue.

Comment: @Doniel maybe but that assumes you didn't do bittul and there's a kezayit. We don't make gezerot to clean up crumbs lest a dog come and eat it.

Comment: @DoubleAA The OP didn’t assume otherwise. Less than a kezayis I agree is only a (Rabbinic) prohibition against eating, but if it’s larger than a Kezayis and you nullify it but don’t remove it from your property, I believe you’re still in violation of בל יראה (since chametz is one of two things which isn’t yours but the Torah treats it as if it is).

Comment: @Doniel no that's only if you didn't do bittul. Then the Torah makes it yours. Point is the OP is looking for leniency in that direction and human edible is seemingly the relevant line for when we worry you'd eat it. He's not looking for leniency about dog relevant rules.